# WordPress error in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

When I try to link up this file in functions.php of WordPress, my site has been blank, I would like to link up the file in functions.php because I want to make the $address variable as dynamic by redux framework, but I can't do that, because redux value is not  getting on that file,
Thanks in advance

```
<?php
if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone     = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">Please fill all fields!</div>';
    exit();
}
else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter your comments</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@themeforest.net";
$address = 'yourmail@gmail.com';


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'Contact Form';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
    echo "<h3>Email Sent Successfully!</h3><br>";
    if ($sender_name==1) : ?>
    <?php echo '<p>'; 
    echo "<strong>$name</strong>"; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $mailcomments; ?> 
    <?php echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";

} else {
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

Comment: open error.log and tell us the error you getting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am just checking now,

Comment: `$address = 'yourmail@gmail.com;` => this line, the closing quote is missing

Comment: Just enable debug mode from wp-config.php file and check the error. https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Not getting any error , it has been just blank, @RafaelShkembi

Comment: As a side note, PHP has a built-in function to validate email : see http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: @Crozet closing quote is okay,it's not missing, thanks

Comment: @RuhulAmin I have enable debug but still it's blank when I call this file,

Comment: Have you checked your server error logs?

Comment: by "error_log" file, @aynber

Comment: There's the error_log that might be in one of the wordpress folders, and then there's the one in /var/log/(apache|httpd|nginx). Check both, as I've found more errors in /var/log than in wordpress.

Comment: Point to be noted : this file is working well without WordPress, but when I try to link up the file in functions.php of WordPress, my whole site has been blank, nothing is showing,

Answer (score 0):

You missed a single quote:

```
$address = 'yourmail@gmail.com;
```

change to:

```
$address = 'yourmail@gmail.com';
```

Comment: this one is ok, it's not missing in that file,